# Way to convert Selenium exe (coded with Python) back into Python source code?

Tags: python, windows, selenium, exe

I have an exe made with Selenium and Python.

Is there a relatively easy way to attempt converting that exe back into Python source code?

This topic is difficult for me- I'm having trouble interpreting other Stackoverflow threads about this. I was hoping that there'd be a tool that I could just upload the exe into and it would attempt doing this, or maybe basic step by step instructions somewhere.

Comment: https://itstillworks.com/convert-exe-code-7230643.html

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/883888/Converting-exe-into-a-readable-source-code

Comment: Those are not about Python exes unfortunately...